# Formula field to count total Accounts linked to Campaign via Contact

Tags: formula-field, account, campaign, campaign-member

Is it possible to count the total number of Accounts (via Contacts) within a Campaign? I would like a field that says something like 'Accounts in Campaign' alongside the other similar fields shown below. I assume it would be a formula field?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula field cannot perform the level of aggregation and analysis that's required here to deduplicate the Accounts of Contacts within the campaign. This requirement would need to be met with code.

The simplest solution, if you can tolerate a less-than-realtime data update, would be an Apex Batch class scheduled to run every night that aggregated Account counts for each Campaign and updated the records. How complex that batch class is would depend in part on the data volume in your Salesforce org; if you have millions or hundreds of millions of Campaign Members, it's a much harder problem than if you have 30,000.